# Having problems with WPF Databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have 2 objects, a Customer and a Store. There are multiple store locations, each customer has a property called PreferredStoreId (int?) which relates to a Store's Id (int).

In a WPF application I am attempting to build a form that allows a customer to be edited. A combo box exists on this form which is filled with Stores to act as a way of displaying the currently set PreferredStore and a way of changing the preferred store.

My problem is, whilst I can populate the combobox, I cannot get two way binding between the Customer.PreferredId (the object set to the UserControl's datacontext) and the combobox's SelectedItem (a Store Object)'s .Id property.

Here Is my XAML to help make sense:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucCustomerEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:localViewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModels"
         xmlns:qc="clr-namespace:QuickConverter;assembly=QuickConverter"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="750" Height="334">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <localViewModels:CustomerViewModel x:Name="customerViewModel" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Height="26" Width="50" Content="Save" Margin="5,10" Click="UserAction_Save" />
        <Button Height="26" Width="50" Content="Cancel" Margin="10,10" Click="UserAction_Cancel" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Height="26" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="209"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Content="First Name:" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Height="26" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="209"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Content="Last Name:" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Height="26" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="209"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding EmailAddress}" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Content="Email Address:" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Height="26" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="209"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Content="Phone Number:" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Height="26" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="209"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Name="cbPreferredStore" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Stores}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=customerViewModel, Path=PreferredStoreId}">
            <ComboBox.DataContext>
                <localViewModels:StoreListViewModel />
            </ComboBox.DataContext>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Content="Preferred Store:" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Height="26" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="209"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Password}" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Content="Password:" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

StoreViewModel code:

```
ublic class StoreViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private enum Modes { CREATE, UPDATE }
    private Modes _mode;
    private Store _store;

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} ({1})", this._store.LocationName, this._store.Id); }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return this._store.Id; }
        set
        {
            this._store.Id = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            notifyPropertyChanged("DisplayName");
        }
    }
    public string LocationName
    {
        get { return this._store.LocationName; }
        set
        {
            this._store.LocationName = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("LocationName");
            notifyPropertyChanged("DisplayName");
        }
    }
    public string ImageURL
    {
        get { return this._store.ImageURL; }
        set
        {
            this._store.ImageURL = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("ImageURL");
        }
    }
    public string AddressLine1
    {
        get { return this._store.AddressLine1; }
        set
        {
            this._store.AddressLine1 = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("AddressLine1");
        }
    }
    public string AddressLine2
    {
        get { return this._store.AddressLine2; }
        set
        {
            this._store.AddressLine2 = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("AddressLine2");
        }
    }
    public string AddressLine3
    {
        get { return this._store.AddressLine3; }
        set
        {
            this._store.AddressLine3 = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("AddressLine3");
        }
    }
    public string Suburb
    {
        get { return this._store.Suburb; }
        set
        {
            this._store.Suburb = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("Suburb");
        }
    }
    public string State
    {
        get { return this._store.State; }
        set
        {
            this._store.State = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("State");
        }
    }
    public string Postcode
    {
        get { return this._store.Postcode; }
        set
        {
            this._store.Postcode = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("Postcode");
        }
    }
    public string Country
    {
        get { return this._store.Country; }
        set
        {
            this._store.Country = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("Country");
        }
    }
    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return this._store.PhoneNumber; }
        set
        {
            this._store.PhoneNumber = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("PhoneNumber");
        }
    }
    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get { return this._store.EmailAddress; }
        set
        {
            this._store.EmailAddress = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("EmailAddress");
        }
    }

    public static explicit operator StoreViewModel(EasyDayTea.Store store)
    {
        return new StoreViewModel(store) { _mode = Modes.UPDATE };
    }

    public StoreViewModel()
    {
        _store = new Store();
        _mode = Modes.CREATE;
    }

    public StoreViewModel(Store store)
    {
        _store = store;
        _mode = Modes.UPDATE;
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        if (_mode == Modes.CREATE)
        {
            _store = new Store() { };
        }
        else
        {
            EasyDayTea.EasyDayTeaClient client = new EasyDayTeaClient();
            _store = client.FetchStore(App.AppUserTeaCredental, _store.Id);
            client.Close();
        }
        notifyAll();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            EasyDayTeaClient client = new EasyDayTeaClient();
            if (_mode == Modes.CREATE)
            {
                client.AddStore(App.AppUserTeaCredental, ImageURL, LocationName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, Suburb, State, Postcode, Country, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                client.SetStore(App.AppUserTeaCredental, Id, ImageURL, LocationName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, Suburb, State, Postcode, Country, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress);
            }
            client.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Your customer was saved.");
            if (_mode == Modes.CREATE)
            {
                _store = new Store();
                notifyAll();
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem saving your customer: \r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    internal void notifyAll()
    {
        notifyPropertyChanged("Id");
        notifyPropertyChanged("LocationName");
        notifyPropertyChanged("ImageURL");
        notifyPropertyChanged("AddressLine1");
        notifyPropertyChanged("AddressLine2");
        notifyPropertyChanged("AddressLine3");
        notifyPropertyChanged("Suburb");
        notifyPropertyChanged("State");
        notifyPropertyChanged("Postcode");
        notifyPropertyChanged("Country");
        notifyPropertyChanged("PhoneNumber");
        notifyPropertyChanged("EmailAddress");
        notifyPropertyChanged("DisplayName");
    }
}
```

StoreListViewModel Code:

```
public class StoreListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private List<StoreViewModel> _stores;

    public List<StoreViewModel> Stores
    {
        get { return this._stores; }
        set
        {
            this._stores = value;
            notifyPropertyChanged("Stores");
        }
    }

    public StoreListViewModel()
    {
        EasyDayTea.EasyDayTeaClient client = new EasyDayTea.EasyDayTeaClient();
        _stores = client.GetStores(App.AppUserTeaCredental).Select(s => (StoreViewModel)s).ToList();
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the implementation of the `Stores` property? Do you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: have u tried to remove the ElementName=customerViewModel, from the binding?

Comment: I have added the StoreListViewModel and the StoreViewModel to the original post. BaseViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `PreferredStoreId` property in CustomerViewModel correctly implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface.

If it's true, then you need change the SelectedValue to `SelectedItem` of your ComboBox, because SelectedItem property returns the entire object which it current selected. However, the [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx) property and the `SelectedValue` uses together as an alternative to the SelectedItem property and as I understand it was not your choice.

Also here:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=customerViewModel, Path=PreferredStoreId}"
```

Not need ElementName, because a CustomerViewModel set the `DataContext` assigned by default.